# Google sheet data validation, text only

Tags: google-sheets, data-validation

I want to make a column (lets say column A) that you can only enter text into it, and reject all numbers.

I have tried "custom" and "=istext()" for the formula... other options don't seem to work

for example:
`2` --> reject
`hello2` --> accept
`12` --> reject

`one2one` --> accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try selecting ColumnA and for validation this formula:

```
=istext(A1)
```

Comment: nope, but this works `=arrayformula(istext(a1:a1000))` ... thanks for the hint

Answer (score -1):

The data validation formula =istext(A1) works for me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/156022)